# How to create a bigger image by repeating a small image

Tags: photoshop, gimp

I have a small image, I want to repeat this image to create a bigger image. I manually tried to copy/paste the image in (ms paing, gimp, photoshop) but could not combine the copies seamlessly. Any program or trick or shortcut for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some images cannot be repeated seamlessly because the edges just wont connect with each other.

I know you asked how to do this in a photo editor, but if you want to see what it will look like to repeat it, without the time and hassle of photoshop, you can throw it into this code to view it:

Copy this code into a text editor, then save the file with .html extension and open it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="background: url(http://root40.joyasolutions.com/Media/rootforty/layout/images/bg.jpg) repeat black;">

    </body>
</html>
```

If you copy this code in and save it you will see my small image repeated creating a large background.  Just replace the link in the parens with either an image link from the web or with an image link from your computer to see how it will look with your picture.

This is the format for a local link:  file:///C:/Users/mary/folder/folder/images/BG.jpg

Good luck.

Comment: I repeated the image with html on the whole page, and captured the screen(lol). Html repeats so neatly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to [create a tileable pattern in GIMP](http://bit.ly/YU32SC).  GIMP also has a feature to create [seamless edges](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-make-seamless.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with Photoshop , I think there is no other programs more powerful than Photoshop
at first open new blank page with greater size than your original Image and drag and drop your image into it and then by copy and paste you can do many copies and create what you want